# Analysis of the most common and salient words in a text

Tags: python, natural-language-processing

I've been trying to get more understanding and experience in the Natural Language Processing space and, to get some more practice, decided to attempt to make a simple high-level analysis of the ["Industrial Society and its Future" (aka "Unabomber Manifesto")](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/national/longterm/unabomber/manifesto.text.htm).

Here is what I am trying to do:

- download the text of the Manifesto from the Washington Post website
- preprocess it using `nltk`:

  - tokenize into words
  - remove the non-alpha words
  - remove English stop words
  - lemmatize the tokens
- count most commonly used words
- use the [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) model from `gensim` library to compute the most popular and most rarely used / important words

The code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from gensim.models.tfidfmodel import TfidfModel
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary

from nltk import word_tokenize, Counter, sent_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

import requests


ENGLISH_STOPS = set(stopwords.words('english'))


def retrieve_text(url):
    """Downloads HTML content from a URL, parses with an HTML parser and returns text only."""
    response = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    return soup.get_text()


def preprocess(text):
    """Pre-processes the text, splits into tokens that are lower-cased, filtered and lemmatized."""
    tokens = word_tokenize(text)

    # lowering
    lower_tokens = [token.lower() for token in tokens]

    # Retain alphabetic words: alpha_only
    alpha_only = [t for t in lower_tokens if t.isalpha()]

    # Remove all stop words: no_stops
    no_stops = [t for t in alpha_only if t not in ENGLISH_STOPS]

    # Lemmatize all tokens into a new list: lemmatized
    wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemmatized = [wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(t) for t in no_stops]

    return lemmatized


def tf_idf(text):
    """
    Computes the TF-IDF of a text - using every sentence as a separate "document".
    Returns a list of tuples with words and weights.
    """
    texts = [preprocess(sentence) for sentence in sent_tokenize(text)]

    dictionary = Dictionary(texts)
    corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]

    tfidf = TfidfModel(corpus)
    corpus_tfidf = tfidf[corpus]

    tfidf_weights = {dictionary.get(id): value
                     for doc in corpus_tfidf
                     for id, value in doc}
    sorted_tfidf_weights = sorted(tfidf_weights.items(), key=lambda w: w[1])

    return sorted_tfidf_weights


if __name__ == '__main__':
    content = retrieve_text("http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/national/longterm/unabomber/manifesto.text.htm")

    tokens = preprocess(content)
    token_counter = Counter(tokens)

    most_common = token_counter.most_common(10)
    tf_idf_results = tf_idf(content)
    popular_terms, rare_terms = tf_idf_results[:10], tf_idf_results[-10:]

    # print out words only (without counts and weights)
    keys = lambda x: next(zip(*x))
    print(f"Most common words: {keys(most_common)}")
    print(f"Most popular terms: {keys(popular_terms)}")
    print(f"Most unique/important terms: {keys(rare_terms)}")
```

Prints:

```
Most common words: ('society', 'system', 'people', 'power', 'would', 'one', 'human', 'technology', 'leftist', 'need')
Most popular terms: ('society', 'people', 'freedom', 'whole', 'human', 'lead', 'system', 'necessity', 'process', 'use')
Most unique/important terms: ('license', 'simplification', 'personnel', 'carried', 'crossroad', 'eminent', 'exactly', 'paramount', 'danger', 'virtue')
```

I am still learning and would like my code to be reviewed. Would appreciate any feedback about the code quality, performance or any other possible improvements.

Also, I am not 100% sure the TF-IDF model is applied in the most appropriate way. Currently, I am treating each sentence as a separate document. Is this a good approach to detect the most "important"/"valuable" terms/words, or should I use other articles/posts as documents for the corpus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I will start with `PEP 8` specifications. The `PEP 8` analysis shows the following:

```
E501:17:80:line too long (94 > 79 characters)
E501:25:80:line too long (99 > 79 characters)
E501:46:80:line too long (82 > 79 characters)
E501:66:80:line too long (114 > 79 characters)
E731:76:5:do not assign a lambda expression, use a def
W292:79:62:no newline at end of file
```

If I am not incorrect, one of the things that you are trying is to calculate the frequency distribution of words, namely the most common words and most rare words. I tried to re-write your code like viz.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from nltk import FreqDist, re

import requests

def retrieve_text(url):
    """Downloads HTML content from a URL, parses with an HTML parser and returns text only."""
    response = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    return soup.get_text()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    content = retrieve_text("http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/national/longterm/unabomber/manifesto.text.htm")
    wordList = re.sub("[^\w]", " ", content).split()
    fdist = FreqDist(wordList)

    # print out words only (without counts and weights)
    print(fdist.most_common(20))
```

As you see in the output, I am obviously not skipping `connector`words, like `the`,  `of` etc.:

```
[('the', 1735), ('of', 1251), ('to', 1078), ('a', 736), ('and', 719), ('that', 657), ('is', 611), ('in', 546), ('be', 412), ('for', 351), ('it', 319), ('or', 290), ('are', 281), ('have', 246), ('society', 239), ('not', 235), ('will', 233), ('as', 230), ('by', 229), ('they', 224)]
```

but, the execution was much faster and I did not have to spend a huge time downloading the `gensim` library. Off course if you need something as sophisticated as `gensim`, I have no substitute, else for frequency, this maybe much faster and you can easily write a method to remove `connector` words.

Answer (score 2):

## Caching

One important step would be to download the page only if it hasn't been downloaded before. This way, the script might run a bit faster, it also works without Internet connection and your name doesn't appear on a "No Fly List" because you've downloaded the Unabomber manifesto a hundred times.

```
from gensim.models.tfidfmodel import TfidfModel
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary

from nltk import word_tokenize, Counter, sent_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

import os


ENGLISH_STOPS = set(stopwords.words('english'))


def retrieve_text(url):
    """Downloads HTML content from a URL, parses with an HTML parser and returns text only."""
    html_filename = os.path.basename(url)
    txt_filename = os.path.splitext(html_filename)[0] + '.txt'

    if not os.path.exists(txt_filename):
        if not os.path.exists(html_filename):
            import requests
            response = requests.get(url)
            with open(html_filename, 'wb') as html:
                html.write(response.content)

        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        with open(html_filename, 'rb') as html:
            with open(txt_filename, 'w') as txt:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")
                txt.write(soup.get_text())

    with open(txt_filename) as txt:
        return txt.read()
```

## Generators

You don't actually need `lower_tokens`, `alpha_only` or `no_stops` as lists. They could be generators. This way, you keep the comments and the variable names, but you only iterate once over `tokens` and don't create unneeded lists.

```
# lowering
lower_tokens = (token.lower() for token in tokens)

# Retain alphabetic words: alpha_only
alpha_only = (t for t in lower_tokens if t.isalpha())

# Remove all stop words: no_stops
no_stops = (t for t in alpha_only if t not in ENGLISH_STOPS)
```

Answer (score 1):

One obvious improvement to performance can be made in `preprocess`. Currently you are using 4 list comprehensions to do your processing. This means you are storing 4 copies of the data, and making 4 passes through the data. By combining steps, you should see a noticeable performance boost. The following should be a fair bit faster, especially for longer text.

```
def preprocess(text):
    """Pre-processes the text, splits into tokens that are lower-cased, filtered and lemmatized."""

    # lowering
    # Retain alphabetic words: alpha_only
    # Remove all stop words: no_stops
    tokens = (token.lower() for token in word_tokenize(text)
                            if t.isalpha()
                            and t.lower() not in ENGLISH_STOPS)

    # Lemmatize all tokens into a new list: lemmatized
    wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    return = [wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(t) for t in tokens]
```

Other than that your code looks pretty good.

Comment: Have you actually timed this? As this looks to me to be reducing memory usage, where _performance_ is roughly the same.

Comment: In general reduced memory leads to better performance mainly when working with large amounts of data. With small files it should be about the same.

Comment: Performance and memory usage are usually trade-offs, and I can only see a marginal speedup from your change, at best. Heck due to two `token.lower()`s, it could be tons worse.

Comment: Since there is no speed penalty, and it uses less memory, I'd still call it a win.

Comment: Nowhere do you mention 'less memory' in you answer, you only talk about speed.